# Standalone BIG-IP with 2-NIC deployment on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, f5

Trying to provisioning Standalone BIG-IP with 2-NIC deployment on GCP through Terraform. Getting below error when executing the Terraform.

```
module.instance.google_compute_instance.bigip[0]: Creating...
module.instance.google_compute_instance.bigip[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
module.instance.google_compute_instance.bigip[0]: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
module.instance.google_compute_instance.bigip[0]: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
module.instance.google_compute_instance.bigip[0]: Still creating... [40s elapsed]

Error: Error waiting for instance to create: Networks must be distinct for NICs attached to a VM.
```

I am following **https://github.com/memes/terraform-google-f5-bigip/tree/main/examples/standalone-2nic** article to provisioning 2 NIC.

I've replaced all required inputs

```
project_id         = "my-project-id"
zone               = "us-west1-c"
external_subnet    = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/ext-west"
management_subnet  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project-id/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/mgmt-west"
admin_password_key = "bigip-admin-password-key"
service_account    = "bigip@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Each NIC interface must be attached to a different VPCs network. The error message is informing you that you are attaching to the same VPC.

[Creating instances with multiple network interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces)